# Running test with --grep returns 0 passing

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, javascript, hardhat

I am using hardhat and trying to run tests with the command-

```
yarn hardhat test --grep "amount funded"
```

FundMe.test.js code-

```
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
describe("FundMe", async function () {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator
    const sendValue = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
    beforeEach(async function () {
        // const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        // const accountZero = accounts[0]
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer)
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract(
            "MockV3Aggregator",
            deployer
        )
    })
    describe("constructor", async function () {
        it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async function () {
            const response = await fundMe.gePriceFeed()
            assert.equal(response, await mockV3Aggregator.getAddress())
        })
    })

    describe("fund", async function () {
        it("Fails if you dont send enough ETH", async function () {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
                "You need to spend more"
            )
        })
        it("amount funded", async function () {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
            const response = await fundMe.addressToAmountFunded(deployer)
            assert.equal(response.toString(), sendValue.toString())
        })
    })
})
```

After running this returns

```
0 passing (62ms)

Done in 7.21s.
```

This is the contract code-

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// 1. Pragma
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// 2. Imports
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "./PriceConvertor.sol";

// 3. Interfaces, Libraries, Contracts
error FundMe__NotOwner();

/**@title A sample Funding Contract
 * @author Samarth Bagga
 * @notice This contract is for creating a sample funding contract
 * @dev This implements price feeds as our library
 */
contract FundMe {
    // Type Declarations
    using PriceConverter for uint256;

    // State variables
    uint256 public constant MINIMUM_USD = 50 * 10**18;
    address private immutable i_owner;
    address[] private s_funders;
    mapping(address => uint256) private s_addressToAmountFunded;
    AggregatorV3Interface private s_priceFeed;

    // Events (we have none!)

    // Modifiers
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        // require(msg.sender == i_owner);
        if (msg.sender != i_owner) revert FundMe__NotOwner();
        _;
    }

    // Functions Order:
    //// constructor
    //// receive
    //// fallback
    //// external
    //// public
    //// internal
    //// private
    //// view / pure

    constructor(address priceFeed) {
        s_priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeed);
        i_owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /// @notice Funds our contract based on the ETH/USD price
    function fund() public payable {
        require(
            msg.value.getConversionRate(s_priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD,
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        );
        // require(PriceConverter.getConversionRate(msg.value) >= MINIMUM_USD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        s_addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        s_funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        for (
            uint256 funderIndex = 0;
            funderIndex < s_funders.length;
            funderIndex++
        ) {
            address funder = s_funders[funderIndex];
            s_addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        s_funders = new address[](0);
        // Transfer vs call vs Send
        // payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
        (bool success, ) = i_owner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success);
    }

    function cheaperWithdraw() public onlyOwner {
        address[] memory funders = s_funders;
        // mappings can't be in memory, sorry!
        for (
            uint256 funderIndex = 0;
            funderIndex < funders.length;
            funderIndex++
        ) {
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            s_addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        s_funders = new address[](0);
        // payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
        (bool success, ) = i_owner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success);
    }

    /** @notice Gets the amount that an address has funded
     *  @param fundingAddress the address of the funder
     *  @return the amount funded
     */
    function getAddressToAmountFunded(address fundingAddress)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return s_addressToAmountFunded[fundingAddress];
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_priceFeed.version();
    }

    function getFunder(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_funders[index];
    }

    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return i_owner;
    }

    function getPriceFeed() public view returns (AggregatorV3Interface) {
        return s_priceFeed;
    }
}
```